# Resource controller route as / (usually this is IndexController), routes not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller called QuestionsController which is the index controller of my app. So when I go to "mydomain.com/" it will call the index method of this controller. This works. But when I got to "mydomain.com/5" I get a `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:`

Below is my resource route:

```
Route::resource('/', 'QuestionsController');
```

Are resource controller routes no good for root. It really suites my app to be this way. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change your route:

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'QuestionsController@getSingle')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

2. add `getSingle($id)` method to `QuestionsController`